# Number-Phase uncertainty relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, coherent-states

I was trying to understand the Number-Phase uncertainty mainly following "A. Duncan, The Conceptual Framework of QFT", pages 223-233 and I got stuck into the definition of the operator
$$E = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}  |n\rangle \langle n+1| + |N \rangle \langle0|$$
It seems that this guy, with its real and imaginary parts $C$ and $S$ solves the troubles in the definition of a phase operator. I know about the issues coming from the definition of a periodic operator, but the way the $E$ operator acts on coherent states $|\alpha \rangle$is obscure to me. The best thing I could do was to evaluate the mean value using Spectral theorem
$$\langle \alpha|E|\alpha \rangle = \int d\Phi e^{i\Phi}|\langle \alpha|\Phi \rangle|^{2}$$ with $|\langle \alpha|\Phi \rangle|^2 \sim e^{-(\theta -\Phi)^2}$ which I don't know how to solve. The book seems to circumvent the problem by looking only at the Gaussian wavepacket itself to get the saturation of the Number-Phase uncertainty, but the above mean value is also useful to check the constance in time of uncertainties with Ehrenfest theorem.

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the first equation. Also, use *\langle*, *\rangle* instead of $<$, $>$ for bras and kets.

Comment: Thank you, gonna correct it

Comment: It could be useful to add to the question the result of this operator acting on a general coherent state - it actually might solve your problem... though the finite number of states $N$ puzzles me a bit.

Comment: The finite number of states is necessary to the application of the polar decomposition theorem which splits the destruction operator $a$ into $E*\sqrt{N}$. However, it can be shown that the occupation of low and high number states drops down exponentially, so truncating the space produces negligible errors. The point is the evaluation of $E$ itself over a coherent state. I've also tryed writing all wrt the Fock basis, but I hitted a dead end.